# TypeScript array find() method saying, "No overload matches this call"

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

**Problem Statement**

I am using TypeScript's `find()` method for an array, but when I input a `value`, it does not work and says, "No overload matches this call".

---

**Code**

```
addOption(event: MatChipInputEvent) {
    const input = event.input;
    const value = event.value;

    // Makes sure that the same element is not inserted in the the options array
    if (value !== this.options.find(value)) {
      // Add our option
      if ((value || '').trim()) {
        this.options.push(value.trim());
      }
    }

    // Reset the input value
    if (input) {
      input.value = '';
    }
  }
```

---

**Explanation of Code**

As you can see, I am using the `find` method in the *first* `if` condition to check and prevent the same element from coming into the array. The value you see there has a red underline and gives me the error, "No overload matches this call". I seem to be doing everything syntactically correct but the error is still there.

---

**Actual Results**

The find method gives me the error, "No overload matches this call" and does not accept the value in the parameters.

---

**Expected Results**

The find method to take in the value and find the element in the array.

Comment: Here's the documentation of find(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find. It doesn't expect a value. It expects a predicate. If you want to test if an array contains a value, you're looking for includes(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: Can you place an answer on how to fix it?

Comment: How about reading the documentation mentioned in the first comment? It also contains examples on how to use the method.

Comment: You should be able to answer your own question if you take 2 minutes to read the documentation. Please do. It's an invaluable skill.

Comment: I was under the assumption that using the find method was the correct way of doing things. I read the find method's doc and was confused because I was doing everything correctly according to it.

Comment: No you aren't... First argument: _"Function to execute on each value in the array, taking 3 arguments"_

Comment: Well then I misread the doc, because what I saw was the first argument needed to be a value and the rest were optional. Looks like I need to go back to reading school ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), you should use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```
if (!this.options.includes(value)) {
```

In case you really want to use `find`, it can be done as follows:

```
if (this.options.find(o => o === value) == undefined) {
```